# двойной bind задачка

Tags: javascript

Может кто нить объяснить, почему в итоге выводится информация из первого `bind`, а не последнего?

```js
function f() {
  console.log(this.name);
}

f = f.bind({name: "Вася"}).bind({name: "Петя"});

f(); // Вася
```

Comment: Объяснить что??

Answer (score 1):

Для начала заменим стандартный метод `bind` на свою функцию, которая делает все то же самое. Связывает контекст

```js
function myBind(func, thisArg) {
  return (function() {
    func.apply(thisArg);
  });
}

function f() {
  console.log(this.name);
}

f = myBind(myBind(f, {name: "Вася"}), {name: "Петя"});

// Эквивалентно следующим двум строкам
//f = myBind(f, {name: "Вася"})
//f = myBind(f, {name: "Петя"});

f();
```

А теперь в нашу функцию `myBind` добавим логирование

```js
function objToStr(obj) {
  if (obj == window)
    return "window";
  else
    return JSON.stringify(obj);
}

function myBind(func, thisArg, desc) {
  console.log("Bind: Desc: " + desc + ", thisArg: " + objToStr(thisArg) + ", this:" + objToStr(this));
  return (function() {
    console.log("Call: Desc: " + desc + ", thisArg: " + objToStr(thisArg) + ", this:" + objToStr(this));
    func.apply(thisArg);
  });
}

function f() {
  console.log(this.name);
}

f = myBind(f, {name: "Вася"}, "first")
f = myBind(f, {name: "Петя"}, "second");

console.log("After Bind");

f();
```

Т.е. в итоге наш вызов `f()` последовательно вызывает две обертки и в конце - нашу функцию

Answer (score 1):

И немного [спецификации](https://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-function.prototype.bind). Функция `bind` возвращает так называемый *exotic object* - похожий на функцию, но не функцию.

У этого объекта есть [три *внутренних* поля](https://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-bound-function-exotic-objects):

1. `[[BoundTargetFunction]]` - ссылка на функцию, у которой вызвали `bind`
2. `[[BoundThis]]` - значение `this`, которое будет передаваться при вызове функции
3. `[[BoundArguments]]` - список значений, которые будут использованы как первые параметры при вызове функции

Кроме того, у данного объекта переопределен метод внутренний [метод `Call`](https://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-bound-function-exotic-objects-call-thisargument-argumentslist).
Он работает следующим образом:

1. К списку аргументов сохраненных в поле `[[BoundArguments]]` добавляются аргументы переданные при вызове
2. Вызов функции сохраненной в `[[BoundTargetFunction]]` с передачей в качестве `this` значения поля `[[BoundThis]]` и обновленного списка аргументов.

Таким образом для кода

```
function f() {...}

var firstBind = f.bind({name: "Вася"})
var secondBind = fisrtBind.bind({name: "Петя"});

secondBind(); // Вася
```

вызов `secondBind()` равносилен вызову `firstBind.call({name: "Петя"})`, что, в свою очередь, равносильно вызову `f.call({name: "Вася"})` так как при вызове экзотического объекта `this` для вызываемой функции устанавливается непосредственно из его внутреннего поля.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ (объяснение) же уже дан(о)! Вот [здесь](https://learn.javascript.ru/bind) (или, если ближе к вопросу, то [здесь](https://learn.javascript.ru/task/second-bind)).

Процитирую главное:

> Первый вызов f.bind(..Вася..) возвращает «обёртку», которая
>   устанавливает контекст для f и передаёт вызов f.
>
> Следующий вызов bind будет устанавливать контекст уже для этой
>   обёртки. Это ни на что не повлияет.

Comment: Зашёл, чтобы освежить в памяти детали работы *bind*, а там тот же вопрос!

Comment: Удивительное рядом...